# MS Access - Add most recent price for each new purchase

Tags: ms-access

I work with this data in table Purchases:

```
Mat_ID     Date          Price
11         5.1.2018      10
11         7.1.2018      12
11         9.1.2018      14
12         5.1.2018      10
12         7.1.2018      12
13         9.1.2018      14
13         5.1.2018      10
```

My desired output query is to have another column with last purchase Price:

```
Mat_ID     Date          Price   PrevPrice
11         5.1.2018      10      Null
11         7.1.2018      12      10
11         9.1.2018      14      12
12         5.1.2018      10      Null
12         7.1.2018      12      10
13         9.1.2018      14      Null
13         5.1.2018      10      14
```

Can you recommend something, please?
Thank you!

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: I tried this and it asks me for a.ICM_CODE:  
  
`SELECT a.ICM_CODE, a.PER_DATE
FROM Vydaje AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 PER_DATE 
FROM Vydaje 
WHERE Vydaje.ICM_CODE=a.ICM_CODE ORDER BY PER_DATE DESC)  AS udaj1 
ON a.PER_DATE = udaj1.PER_DATE;`

Comment: I know this code is not getting price, but I tried to get last date to verify.

Comment: This is what I have at test SQL server, but I need it in Access and it does not recognize Row_number.  
`select a.*,b.price,b.date_1, b.row_num, b.mat_ID, a.date_1-b.date_1 as diff from
(select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition  by mat_ID order by date_1 ) as row_num, mat_ID,price,date_1
         from tablename
         ) a
         left outer join
         (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() over(partition  by mat_ID order by date_1 ) as row_num,
       mat_ID
      ,price
      ,date_1
         from tablename  
         ) b on a.mat_ID = b.mat_ID and a.row_num = b.row_num+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
    *, 
    (Select Top 1 Price 
    From YourTable As T 
    Where T.Mat_ID = YourTable.Mat_ID And T.[Date] < YourTable.[Date] 
    Order By T.Mat_ID, T.[Date] Desc) As PrevPrice
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the Order By. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you @Gustav, but I see query with empty column PrevPrice in background and error "At most one record can be returned by this subquery.".

Comment: OK, you may have to include also `Mat_ID` in the Order By. See edited answer, please.